# Number of homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ to $\mathbb{Z}_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Task is in the title.

My attempt:

> All elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ have order $2$, except $(0,0)$, which has order $1$. This means that the only possible mapping from $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ to $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is to map $\{(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$ to $2$, since $2$ is the only element in $\mathbb{Z}_4$ that has order $2$, and map $(0,0)$ to $0$. However, consider $(1,0)+(1,1)=(0,1)$. With this homomorphism in mind, we get that $2+2=0$ which would be wrong since $0=(0,0)$, but this doesn't respect group operations from $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ since we should obtain $(0,1)$. Hence, there are no homomorphisms between these groups.

Is this correct?

Comment: There are never *no* homomorphisms between two groups; in particular, there's always the trivial homomorphism which sends everything to the identity. With that example in mind, think about other cases you've missed. (Are you confusing homomorphism and isomorphism?)

Comment: Yes i was. However, im still having difficulty understanding how im supposed to find homomorphisms in general. If i'm working with isomorphisms , i can look at generators and how they transfer over, but homomorphisms im not sure.

Comment: @Hristmar In general this is a hard problem but it's doable for these very small groups.

Comment: How? Do i just consider every permutation of mappings?

Comment: To add to what @CyclotomicField said, for finite abelian groups this problem is always "easy" (once you know enough).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct general rule is that when we're looking at a homomorphism $\phi : G \to H$, if an element $g \in G$ has order $k$, then the order of $\phi(g)$ must be *some divisor* of $k$.

That's because $\underbrace{g + g + \dots + g}_{k \text{ times}} = e_G$, so $\underbrace{\phi(g) + \phi(g) + \dots + \phi(g)}_{k \text{ times}} = \phi(e_G) = e_H$, but on the other hand, it's possible that a smaller multiple of $\phi(G)$ is also equal to $e_H$.

So in your case, you're right to start by observing that the non-identity elements of $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ have order $2$. What this means is that they must map to elements of order $1$ or $2$ in $\mathbb Z_4$: that is, either to $0$ or to $2$.

You've already ruled out the case where all three of them map to $2$. In fact, turning your argument on its head: once we specify what $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ map to, that uniquely determines what $(1,1)$ must map to. This means we have at most four choices: $\phi(1,0)$ is either $0$ or $2$, and $\phi(0,1)$ is either $0$ or $2$.

Check that all four of those choices work.

Comment: So if im understanding you correctly, we can figure out the number of homomorphisms by considering all possible mappings of the generating set of G, then check whether the group functions properly under these homomorhpisms?

Comment: Yes. There are sometimes shortcuts, but that strategy will always work.

Comment: Thank you! I understand your explanation.

Comment: The part on elements' orders can be replaced by noting that  $\phi(C_2\times C_2)$ must be a proper subgroup of $C_4$. Also, the last sentence is well due, since we are dealing with just *necessary* conditions for $\phi$ to be a homomorphism. +1

Answer (score 2):

Let $C_2\times C_2=\{a_0:=0,a_1,a_2,a_3:=a_1+a_2\}$ and $f$ be such a homomorphism; then, $f(C_2\times C_2)$ is a *proper* subgroup of $C_4$ (because $C_2\times C_2\ncong C_4$), namely either $f(C_2\times C_2)=\{0\}$ or $f(C_2\times C_2)=\{0,2\}$. The first case corresponds to the trivial homomorphism $a_i\mapsto 0, i=0,1,2,3$; the second to the $7$ "candidate" maps identified by the condition:

$$f(a_0)=0 \space\wedge\space \exists\alpha \in \{1,2,3\}\mid f(a_\alpha)=2 \tag 1$$

But, these latter are constrained by the condition:

$$f(a_3)=f(a_1+a_2)=f(a_1)+f(a_2) \tag 2$$

which rules out:

1. $(f(a_1),f(a_2),f(a_3))=(2,2,2)$, because $2\ne 2+2=0$;
2. $(f(a_1),f(a_2),f(a_3))=(2,0,0)$, because $0\ne 2+0=2$;
3. $(f(a_1),f(a_2),f(a_3))=(0,2,0)$, because $0\ne 0+2=2$;
4. $(f(a_1),f(a_2),f(a_3))=(0,0,2)$, because $2\ne 0+0=0$.

So, we are left with the $3$ nontrivial maps:

\begin{alignat}{1}
(f(a_0),f(a_1),f(a_2),f(a_3)) &= (0,2,2,0) \\
&= (0,2,0,2) \\
&= (0,0,2,2) \\
\tag 3
\end{alignat}

which indeed all turn out to be homomorphisms.

---

$($Alternatively, if we are interested just in the number of such homomorphisms, we can note that there are as many nontrivial of them as the (normal) subgroups of order $2$ of $C_2\times C_2$, which are precisely $3$, namely $N_\alpha:=\{0,a_\alpha\}, \space\alpha=1,2,3$.$)$